# JQuery AutoSuggest to determine URL

Tags: php, jquery, url, search, autosuggest

Does anyone have an idea on how to integrate http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ to determine a URL?

For example, when I type in Kim, it would associate her name with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLuUOaczxe0. So when I submit the form it will redirect me to that page.

Comment: Did you have a database that translate tag into url? Or already have some public API for your plan?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Download jquery autocomplete and navidate to `development-bundle\demos\autocomplete\` in the zip file. There you can find `search.php`. There, you may associate your links with your custom keywords.

Hope this helps